# How to create new list view using New Experience Lists inside office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, list-view, custom-list, new-experience

I am working on a custom list inside a team site collection and I added a new custom list with the list experience set to "**New experience**"

[image]

I can modify the default view, but I can not find from where I can add additional list view for my custom list, as seems the menu does not contain an option to add new list view.

[image]

Comment: Change the order or filter items and you should be able to save the current view as a new one... (select Save View in the dropdown)

Comment: @Murphy i want to change the filter and other settings.. so why i can not just create a new list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list with the **New Experience** you can create new Views for the list by going to the **List Settings** for the specific list. Unlike the Classic Experience, to get to the List Setting you click the gear icon from the top menu. You will see it as an option from the drop down.

[image]

After clicking List Settings, scroll to the bottom of the page and you will see a section named **Views**. This is where you can create new views for your list.